# jQuery in firefox extension

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon

I was creating a firefox extension.
and I am  including the jquery in the xul file as

```
    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="libs/project/libs/jquery.js" />
```

followed by some other files which uses jquery

```
    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="sample.js" />
    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="sample2.js" />
                     .
                     .
                     .
```

but here I am getting some errors like

- ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
- TypeError: a is undefined
- ReferenceError: $ is not defined

what should I do ?

Comment: Which script is throwing the errors?

Comment: the sampple1.js and sample2.js (all scripts that uses $ and jQuery)

Comment: I can think of three possibilities; (1) the path to `jquery.js` is wrong, (2) `type="application/x-javascript"` is not appropriate; (3) something else redefines `jQuery` and `$`.

Comment: (1)  I am able to see the jquery.js code by following the link in the error console (2) same thing happens when I use just the script tag without type (3) I added  jQuery.noConflict();
    $ = function(selector,context) { 
        return new jQuery.fn.init(selector,context||example.doc); 
    };
    $.fn = $.prototype = jQuery.fn;  now  $ is not defined error is not coming , how can i avoid jQuery is not defined error?

Comment: Hrishi, try `$jq = jQuery.noConflict();` immediately after loading "...libs/jquery.js". Then see if `$jq` acts as a reliable alias for `jQuery` in the other scripts.

Comment: The thing is , most of the other scripts are library files which I don't want to touch. :(

Comment: Hrishi, I'm fresh out of ideas. Try searching to see if anyone else has reported the same issue with FF extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible reason for this is this bug: 
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12357

JQUERY 1.8.0 NOT PARSEABLE BY XUL RUNNER APPLICATIONS

You can test this by setting up a simple xul runner window and including jQuery, then alert the typeof jQuery or $ which will result in a response of undefined.

If you paste the jQuery code into a script tag in the XUL main window, you will be able to see all the various parsing issues that have been released in this build.

Comment: According to your link, that bug is fixed now