# firefox addon XMLHttpRequest not working

Tags: ajax, firefox, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon

I have below code to send string from Firefox addon to MySQL. It works if I run by console i.e. I get data in MySQL. But when I add it to the extension it doesn't work. Even the line above of this script in the extension (which write text to a text file) runs i.e. write to that text file.

I referred below links

[XMlHttpRequest is not working in Firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797982/xmlhttprequest-is-not-working-in-firefox-extension)

[How to use jQuery in Firefox Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491490/how-to-use-jquery-in-firefox-extension?rq=1)

[jQuery in Firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137353/jquery-in-firefox-extension?lq=1)

[jQuery in firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960797/jquery-in-firefox-extension?rq=1)

[Adding Jquery and Other JS libraries to Firefox Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112111/adding-jquery-and-other-js-libraries-to-firefox-extension?rq=1)

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("GET", "http://localhost/todayreport/ajax.php?firefoxaddondata=data", true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
http.send();
```

Comment: What is your context? Are you using addon sdk? or classic bootstrap/jsm? Or worker?

Comment: Noitidart, Mine is xul addon. Sorry I forget to mention it.

Comment: Then instead of `new XMLHttpRequest()` do `createInstance` so: `Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIXMLHttpRequest);`

Comment: I tried adding `const {Cc, Ci, Cu, components} = require("chrome");` and modified `new XMLHttpRequest()` to `Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIXMLHttpReque‌​st);`, But is this the right way? shouldn't we convert it to bootstrap? I got this question because the above changes have no effect. Actually I try this thing because I couldn't convert the addin for this code from xul to restartless as my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783930/firefox-addon-could-not-convert-to-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

in my bootstrap extension i added this at the top

```
const XMLHttpRequest = Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1", "nsIXMLHttpRequest");
```

then you can use normally

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```